# Images loaded lazily and replaced with placeholders

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux

I'm getting some images from the reddit API in my React/Redux and I thought about lazy loading them by setting their `loading` attributes to `lazy`.

But I'll get this message in DevTools:

> [Intervention] Images loaded lazily and replaced with placeholders.
> Load events are deferred. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2048113

I couldn't find anything on the web about it so I wanted to ask in Stackoverflow what that message means.

Answer (score 0):

Hey If any one wonder what this error is.

you can set the type of loading to the image attribute

<img src= alt="" loading="lazy" />

<img src= alt="" loading="eager" />

LazyImages is a mechanism in Blink that defers images below the viewport from being loaded until they are likely to be viewed, in order to save data and speed up loading of the elements in the viewport. It will be used as part of the LazyLoad feature

Hope this Helps.
Just Remove the Type of Loading so your code is eternal - Just Joking.

Answer (score -2):

I got rid of the warning by setting the loading Attribute to "eager" instead of "lazy".
Its behavior is a bit Different, but you still get Performance benefits

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Answer doesn't address the question "what that message means". Also, it would be of interest, how to make this message dissapear without changing the desired behaviour.